# Who is Picard's favorite philosopher?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, jean-luc-picard

I know Picard is quite a humanities fan and speaks to Wesley about philosophy during their trip to a starbase when to get his heart operation conducted.  That got me to thinking - does Picard ever say who his favorite philosopher actually is and, if so, who would that person be?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, Picard never says who his favourite philosopher is, and anyone with an interest in philosophy would never pick a "favourite" anyway. Picard strikes me as a man interested in the search for 'truth;' no-one interested in truth would limit themselves in such a way.

Comment: My wife says the exact opposite.

Comment: deep. that answer was like philosophy all in itself!

Comment: @JamesSheridan - such is the nature of marriage </philosophy>